# docker-entrypoint.sh : Only exec "$@" not working

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile, kerberos

I was struggling to fix this issue from couple of days.

File 1 : docker-entrypoint.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
source /home/${HADOOP_INSTALL_USERNAME}/.bashrc
kinit -kt /home/${HADOOP_INSTALL_USERNAME}/keytab/dept-test-hadoop.${HADOOP_INSTALL_ENV}.keytab dept-test-hadoop
mkdir /tmp/test222222
exec "$@"
```

Dockerfile :

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/home/dept-test-hadoop/docker-entrypoint.sh"]
```

docker run command :

```
docker run -it hadoop-hive:v1 /bin/mkdir /tmp/test1
```

The challenge or what I am trying is to execute what ever the command that pass as command-line argument to docker run command.Please note these commands required kerberos authentication

1) I have noticed `/tmp/test222222` but I could not see a directly like `/tmp/test1` with above docker run command. I think my exec `"$@"` in docker-entrypoint.sh not executing. But I can confirm the script is executing as I can see the `/tmp/test222222`

2) Is there way that we can assign the values from environment variables ?

`ENTRYPOINT ["/home/dept-test-hadoop/docker-entrypoint.sh"]`

Comment: Add `set -x` to trace commands as they're executed, and [edit] the log of what's actually invoked into the question. BTW, are you sure `/bin/mkdir` *actually exists*, and that the container in question doesn't maybe have mkdir in `/usr/bin` instead?

Comment: (Also, I'm curious -- how are you checking which files are transiently created inside the container, when the container no longer exists the moment the `exec`'d command is done?)

Comment: What are you actually trying to do in the long run? As @CharlesDuffy mentioned, what you are doing is likely working, but your container exits as soon as the exec'd process exits. A container that creates a directory and exits doesn't seem very useful. Is the intent to set up some directories and then run something? BTW, you can replace `exec "$@"` with `"$@"; exec /bin/bash` to see the directory is there.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy @hmm,  Thanks for helping me, actually I was trying to execute some hadoop commands, like this.

```
docker run -it hadoop-hive:v1 <hadoop command> OR


docker run -it hadoop-hive:v1 sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://database-server:3301/sqoopsample  --table employees --username DBUSER -P --target-dir /tmp/sqoopOut1 -m 1
```

I am trying to create a executable docker image, which has kerberso ticket ready. 

Then I can execute the docker run comand with various hadoop commands.

Comment: @UtpMahesh Well, perhaps my suggestion will work then. Run whatever is passed to `docker run -it` in your entrypoint script with `"$@"` and then exec a shell so that the container doesn't die.

Comment: @hmm, `exec "$@"` is ever so slightly more efficient than just `"$@"`, since it doesn't `fork()` a subprocess; so I don't want to discourage it when it's the last line of a script and no exit/cleanup traps or other subsequent actions are expected.

Answer (score 3):

You container will exit as long as it creates the directory. You container life is the life of  `exec` command or docker-entrypoint, so your container will die soon after `exec "$@"`.

If you are looking for a way to create a directory from env then you can try this

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
source /home/${HADOOP_INSTALL_USERNAME}/.bashrc
kinit -kt /home/${HADOOP_INSTALL_USERNAME}/keytab/dept-test-hadoop.${HADOOP_INSTALL_ENV}.keytab dept-test-hadoop
mkdir $MY_DIR
ls
exec "$@"
```

so now pass `MY_DIR` to env but keep the long process in mind.

```
docker run -it -e MY_DIR=abcd hadoop-hive:v1  "your_long_running_process_to_exec"
```

for example

```
docker run -it -e MY_DIR=abcd hadoop-hive:v1 "<hadoop command>"
```

If you run any process from ENV in exec then also you can try

```
#!/bin/sh
set -x
mkdir $MY_DIR
ls
exec ${START_PROCESS}
```

so you can pass during run time

```
docker run -it -e MY_DIR=abcd -e START_PROCESS=my_process hadoop-hive:v1
```

Comment: BTW, `set -e` is [not necessarily a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises).